# C# + Selenium : StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using C# and Selenium, while clicking a text in the window the page gets refreshed.  Right after the click, it's throwing StaleElementReferenceException

```
xrmBrowser.CommandBar.ClickCommand("Warranty");
xrmBrowser.ThinkTime(8000);
xrmBrowser.Driver.LastWindow();
Log.Info("Look for Active directory button");
var activeDir = xrmBrowser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[text()='Active Directory']"));
if (activeDir.Text is "Active Directory")
{
   activeDir.Click();
   Log.Info("AD Click");
}
```

Log is printing **Look for Active directory button** but not **AD Click**

The Active Directory link is getting clicked and the below error is thrown rightaway

```
exception: OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.551601 (edb21f07fc70e9027c746edd3201443e011a61ed),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
```

On Click of **Active Directory** the page will refresh with some other content.  The next step is to find the heading in that page as below

```
var headingElementOnPage = xrmBrowser.Driver.FindElement(By.TagName("h2"));
```

Any quick help is appreciated.

Comment: if (activeDir.Text is "Active Directory")
{
   xrmBrowser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[text()='Active Directory']")).Click();
   Log.Info("AD Click");
}

Comment: What you mean @SoorajSathianandan

Comment: You need to build the activeDir web element again after you get the text in the if condition. The code is in my previous comment.

Comment: Sorry @SoorajSathianandan No luck, it still fails